# How can i set array of content for <p> tag with one id using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my full code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>[items-carting nums="hbn7wxjxjodpxi2nlmml"]</p>
<p>[items-carting nums="nlmmljodhbni27wxjxpx"]</p>
<p>[items-carting nums="bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx"]</p>
<p>product design</p>
<p>vmware</p>
<script>
var userInput = "items-carting";
var all_script = "This is the value : ";
var all=$("p:contains(" + userInput + ")").attr('id', 'xyz');
var len_all=$('p').length;
var all_array=[];
for (var i=0; i < len_all; i++) {
  all_array.push($(all[i]).text());
}
all_array = all_array.filter(item => item);
changed_array=[];
for (var i = 0; i < all_array.length; i++) 
{ 
var indexEqu=all_array[i].indexOf("=");
var slicedVal=all_array[i].slice(indexEqu+2,indexEqu+22);
var result = all_array[i].replace(all_array[i],all_script);
var out=result+slicedVal+" to be saved";
changed_array.push(out);
}

for (var j = 0; j < changed_array.length; j++) {
$("#xyz").text(changed_array[j]);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I have to set values from array named changed_array in above code to `<p>` tag with `id=xyz` serially .

In current code in only one `<p>` tag value is getting set.

How can I change the values with `id=xyz` to `<p>` tag from array on webpage ?

Expected Output on webpage :

[items-carting nums="hbn7wxjxjodpxi2nlmml"] should change to "This is the value : hbn7wxjxjodpxi2nlmml"

[items-carting nums="nlmmljodhbni27wxjxpx"] should change to "This is the value : nlmmljodhbni27wxjxpx"

[items-carting nums="bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx"] should cange to :This is the value : bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx"

But currently i am getting following output:

This is the value : bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx to be saved

[items-carting nums="nlmmljodhbni27wxjxpx"]

[items-carting nums="bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx"]

product design

vmware

Comment: "*In current code in only one <p> tag value is getting set.*" - only getting its "value" set?  Do you mean only one is getting id=xyz or do you mean only one is getting its *text* set?   `$("#xyz").text(out);` will only apply to one as IDs must be unique within the document and `$("#` knows this, so will only ever find one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a classname instead of id.  id must always be unique, whereas classname can be shared across multiple elements.

```js
var all=$("p:contains(" + userInput + ")").addClass('xyz');
```

```js
for (var j = 0; j < changed_array.length; j++) {
$(".xyz").eq(j).text(changed_array[j]);
}
```

[Here is a more thorough explanation](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) on the differences between class and id if you'd like one.

Comment: Only last element from array is getting set to all <p> tags.
I am getting  below output
This is the value : bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx to be saved

This is the value : bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx to be saved

This is the value : bni27wxjnlmmljodhxpx to be saved

product design

vmware

Comment: when copying your code I failed to notice you had a typo in your `for` loop.  you set `j` as your increment variable but the loop increments `i++`.  make sure the loop uses the same variable throughout.  `for (var j = 0; j < changed_array.length; j++)`

Comment: Ok.  I am unsure what to do with this information.  Do you need more help?

Comment: Yes , because i am getting only last element from an array in <p> tag .

Comment: when you use a query selector that is able to select multiple elements you get an array of those elements.  take care to select one element at a time when changing the text instead of all elements together: `$(".xyz").eq(j).text(changed_array[j]);` see the use of jquery [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function